# Another Error: [$resource:badcfg] in Angular webapp

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm following a [Tuts+ tutorial](https://code.tutsplus.com/courses/building-a-web-app-from-scratch-with-angularjs) on building an AngularJS webapp. Everything went well untill I tried getting JSON data on the screen.

I keep getting the following [Error: [$resource:badcfg]](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$resource/badcfg?p0=query&p1=array&p2=object)

Here's my code:
Service

```
angular.module('ContactsApp')
    .factory('Contact', function ($resource) {
        return $resource('/api/contact/:id', { id: '@id' }, {
            'update': { method: 'PUT' }
        });
    })
```

Controller

```
angular.module('ContactsApp')
.controller('ListController', function($scope, Contact) {
    $scope.contacts = Contact.query();
    $scope.fields = [ 'firstName', 'lastName'];

    $scope.sort = function(field){
        $scope.sort.field = field;
        $scope.sort.order = !$scope.sort.order;
    };

    $scope.sort.field = 'firstName';
    $scope.sort.order = false;

});
```

I have allready searched the web for solutions and tried adding isArray:false to the declaration. I also compared all my code to the full code on [GitHub](https://github.com/tutsplus/Building-a-Web-App-From-Scratch-With-AngularJS), but I can't find the problem.

Comment: This would be based on the data that is returned from the server I think.  Is it sending back an array?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to pass an empty array when defining your module, like this :

```
angular.module('ContactsApp', [])
```